# EXT3 with no (write) cache

Tags: linux, ext3

I want to mount an ext3 filesystem with no caching at all, most importantly no write caches since I want everything to be flushed to disk right away. Can anyone share the needed flags for such a functionality, I am having trouble finding this at the man pages.

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mount -o sync -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

assuming the device is `/dev/sda1` and the mount point is `/mnt`.